# join mysql select queries as 1 then group by

Tags: mysql, sql

Using information of this site I have been able to do the join but im having the issues doing the group by

is there a way to get the below statements to run as 1

Query1

```
SELECT count(location),date 
from `filter` 
where location != "red" 
group by date
```

Query2

```
SELECT count(location),date 
from `filter` 
where location = "red" 
group by date
```

I did try the below but it outputs the wrong data

Query3

```
SELECT 
date,
(select count(location) from `filter` where location != "red") AS indoor, 
(select count(location) from `filter` where location = "red") AS outdoor
from `filter` group by date;
```

SQL Fiddle for each query

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/17ebea/4 (query1)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/17ebea/6 (query2)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90c945/1 (query3)

Comment: Well done! Pretty well formulated question, considering you are new :)

Comment: thank you I took time to read the other question and tips people had given them on how to write question for clearer understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    date,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN location <> 'red' THEN location ELSE NULL END) AS indoor,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN location = 'red' THEN location ELSE NULL END) AS outdoor
FROM filter 
GROUP BY date;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case

Answer (score 0):

You can do conditional aggregation using `CASE.. WHEN` expressions.

```
SELECT 
  date,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN location = 'red' THEN location END) AS outdoor,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN location <> 'red' THEN location END) AS indoor
FROM `filter` 
GROUP BY date;
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hsMzRr3PsjtZedEYjBiLoT/0)

**Result**

```
| date       | outdoor | indoor |
| ---------- | ------- | ------ |
| 2018-11-14 | 1       | 4      |
| 2018-11-15 | 1       | 0      |
| 2018-11-16 | 0       | 3      |
| 2018-11-17 | 1       | 1      |
| 2018-11-18 | 0       | 1      |
| 2018-11-19 | 0       | 2      |
| 2018-11-20 | 0       | 1      |
```

---

You can also use the following other variants, like using `COUNT(1)` instead, or using `SUM(..)` function.

**Alternative #1**

```
SELECT 
  date,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN location = 'red' THEN 1 END) AS outdoor,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN location <> 'red' THEN 1 END) AS indoor
FROM `filter` 
GROUP BY date;
```

**Alternative #2**

```
SELECT 
  date,
  SUM(CASE WHEN location = 'red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS outdoor,
  SUM(CASE WHEN location <> 'red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS indoor
FROM `filter` 
GROUP BY date;
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, I would use the shortcut that allows you to `sum()` boolean variables:

```
select date, sum(location = 'red') as red,
       sum(location <> 'red') as not_red
from filter 
group by date ;
```

Notes:

- Use single quotes for string and date constants -- not double quotes.  Single quotes are the standard delimiter.
- `<>` is the SQL inequality operator, although `!=` is also supported by most databases.
- This does not count `NULL` values.

To handle `NULL` values, you might want:

```
       sum(not location <=> 'red') as not_red
```